# Why does this euclidean distance calculation method explodes RAM usage?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distance, space-complexity

I'm studying the KNN algorithm to classify images using some material from a 2017 Stanford course. We're given a dataset consisting of many images, later those sets are represented as 2D numpy arrays, and we're supposed to write functions that calculate distances between those images. More specifically, given a 2D array of the test images and a 2D array of the training images, I'm asked to write a L_2 distance function, which takes those two sets as inputs and returns a distance matrix, where every row i represents a test image and every column j represents a training image.

The exercise also asked me to do it without any loops and without using `np.abs` function. So I gave it a try and tried:

```
def compute_distances_no_loops(self, X):
    """
    Compute the distance between each test point in X and each training point
    in self.X_train using no explicit loops.

    Input / Output: Same as compute_distances_two_loops
    """
    num_test = X.shape[0]
    num_train = self.X_train.shape[0]
    dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
    all_test_subs_sq = (X[:, np.newaxis] - self.X_train)**2
    dists = np.sqrt(np.sum(all_test_subs_sq), axis = 2)
    return dists
```

Apparently that makes Google's Colab environment crash in 6 seconds due to allocating about 60 GB of RAM. I guess I should clarify the training set `X_train` has a shape of (5000, 3072), and the test set `X` has shape (500, 3072). I am not sure what happens here that is so RAM intensive, but then again I'm not the smartest guy to figure out space complexity.

I googled a bit and found out a solution that works without the need for a NASA computer, it uses the sum of the squares formula:

```
    dists = np.reshape(np.sum(X**2, axis=1), [num_test,1]) + np.sum(self.X_train**2, axis=1)\
- 2 * np.matmul(X, self.X_train.T)
    dists = np.sqrt(dists)
```

I'm also not really sure why doesn't this solution explode like mine did. I'd really appreciate any insight here, thank you very much for reading.

Comment: The size of the result is the product of the sizes of the two input arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `compute_distances_no_loops()` function the intermediate array `all_test_subs_sq` has the shape (500, 3072, 5000), so it consists of 500 * 3072 * 5000 = 7,680,000,000 elements. Assuming that the dtype of `X` and `X_train` is `float64`, each element weights 8 bytes, so the total size of the array is 61,440,000,000 bytes i.e. about 60 GB.

The other solution you included avoids this problem since it does not create such a large intermediate array. The shape of `np.reshape(np.sum(X**2, axis=1), [num_test,1])` is (500, 1) and the shape of `np.sum(self.X_train**2, axis=1)` is (5000,). When you add them you obtain an array of the shape (500, 5000). `np.matmul(X, self.X_train.T)` also produces an array of the same shape.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in

```py
all_test_subs_sq = (X[:, np.newaxis] - self.X_train)**2
```

`X[:, np.newaxis]` is equivalent to `X[:, np.newaxis, :]` of shape `(50, 1, 3072)`. After broadcasting, `X[:, np.newaxis] - self.X_train` yields a **dense** `(500, 5000, 3072)` array which is humongous `500 x 5000 x 3072 x 8 bytes ≈ 61.44 GB` since you have `np.float64`.